# How to conditionally recreate indexes created by `CREATE INDEX ON <table_name> (<column_name>)`?

Tags: postgresql, index, migration, postgresql-13

I am squashing migrations and rewriting all constructs like:

```
CREATE TABLE entities (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  title text NOT NULL,
  description text
);

CREATE INDEX ON entities (title);
CREATE INDEX ON entities (description);
```

Into:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entities (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  title text NOT NULL,
  description text
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ON entities (title);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ON entities (description);
```

When I run the squash I get a syntax error on the `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ON entities (title);` line. After squinting harder at the [docs reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createindex.html) I noticed `IF NOT EXISTS` does in fact require `name` after it.
So what is the right way to conditionally recreate "default" indexes like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use names in `CREATE INDEX` statements, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entities (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  title text NOT NULL,
  description text
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS entities_title_idx ON entities (title);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS entities_description_idx ON entities (description);
```

Comment: Yeah but there is no way to get the name of the index knowing its table and the target column, as far as I know. You either just have to know `CREATE INDEX ON <table_name> (<column_name>);` under the hood creates an index name in the form `{table_name}_{column_name}_idx{sequence}` or you have to get into the running instance and check created indexes one-by-one, which can be quite non-trivial/impossible to do.